# Convert a list of strings to call already set values?

Tags: r

Is it possible to convert a list of strings so that it will return the value it's named after?

For example, I have this list of strings that I made with paste:

```
mylist <- c("nhdata$Credit", "nhdata$Honey", "nhdata$Plants")
mylist
```

The list I'm working with is a lot bigger (about 35). So is it possible to print these strings in a way that it will actually call the value they are named after?

Appreciate any help, this is my first question stackoverflow

Comment: If these are all in the same data frame, then don't use the data.frame name as part of the vector, e.g., `cols = c("mpg", "hp", "am")` then `mtcars[cols]` works just fine. Also you have a vector, not a `list`.

Comment: It's a hacky construction that's best avoided if possible, but if this is really what you've got, you need something like `sapply(mylist, function(x){eval(parse(text = x))})`

Comment: If you need to strip out the data.frame name to use Gregor's approach (which is less hacky), you can use `sub('.*\\$', '', mylist)`

Comment: Gregor's solution works perfect for what I need thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get` function:

```
temp <- 1:10
get("temp")
```

In your example, you may do better to use the following, though:

```
mylist <- c("Credit", "Honey", "Plants")
nhdata[, mylist[1]]
```

or similarly,

```
nhdata[[mylist[1]]]
```